# Apply multiple regular expressions to a text at same time in python

Tags: python, regex

Assume I have a text containing `'.'` and `','` and sometimes they both are followed by empty spaces. I need to write a regular expression which removes [`'.'` and space] or [`','` and space] from the whole text. I have the regular expression as mentioned below:-

```
text = re.sub('[.]+[ ]+', " ", text)
text = re.sub('[,]+[ ]+', " ", text)
```

Here, I am applying multiple patterns to string multiple times. Is there an efficient way to do this in one pass? Also, the output is stored in the same variable. Is this an efficient way or we do have a copy created in this case. Kindly let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using regex's "or" operator, `|`?

Comment: `text = re.sub('([.]+[ ]) | ([,]+[ ])+', " ", text)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are already using character sets, put both . and , into one::

```
text = re.sub('[.,]+ +', " ", text)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the period, not any character, meaning `r'[\.,]+ +'`.

Comment: Inside of character sets, `.` means not any character but literally `.`.

Answer (score 0):

since you need to replace only the . or , followed by a space. you could use

```
text = re.sub('[.,]\s', " ", text)
```